# Unable to install mysqlclient to connect mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I am getting the following error when install mysqlclient.I use pycharm and python 3.6

```
(venv) C:\Users\gselvaraj\PycharmProjects\djano_tutorial>pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/97/7326248ac8d5049968bf4ec708a5d3d4806e412a42e74160d7f266a3e03a/mysqlclient-1.4.6.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\gselvaraj\PycharmProjects\djano_tutorial\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\GSELVA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4v4c77rd\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open',
open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\GSELVA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-5yo0ns17\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\g
selvaraj\PycharmProjects\djano_tutorial\venv\include\site\python3.6\mysqlclient:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\MySQLdb
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\m
ariadb" -IC:\Users\gselvaraj\PycharmProjects\djano_tutorial\venv\include -IC:\Users\gselvaraj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\include -IC:\Users\gselvaraj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\201
9\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program
 Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /TcMySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj /Zl /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    _mysql.c
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\gselvaraj\PycharmProjects\djano_tutorial\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\GSELVA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4v4c77rd\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.r
ead().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\GSELVA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-5yo0ns17\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\gselvaraj\PycharmProjects
\djano_tutorial\venv\include\site\python3.6\mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\GSELVA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4v4c77rd\mysqlclient\

(venv) C:\Users\gselvaraj\PycharmProjects\djano_tutorial>>
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

(venv) C:\Users\gselvaraj\PycharmProjects\djano_tutorial>
(venv) C:\Users\gselvaraj\PycharmProjects\djano_tutorial>>
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
(venv) C:\Users\gselvaraj\PycharmProjects\djano_tutorial>wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.7.3-1_all.deb
'wget' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Please format your question with code blocks.

Comment: last line shows that you have to install program `wget` to get it

Comment: text `Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': ` means you have to download source code of `mysql` (or at least file headers - files *.h) because it want to compile C/C++ code.

Comment: check [official MySQL page](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/) - they may have precompiled module for Windows.